# How to ignore variable not in the checkpoint with tf.Estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using `tf.Estimator` to train and evaluate my models. During evaluation, I'd like to use the tensorboard projector visualization. For that I need to create and fill a variable with the feature I want to visualize. My `model_fn` looks like the following:

```py
def model_fn(...):
  ....
  predictions = net(features, is_training=is_training)
  ...

  if mode == ModeKeys.EVAL:
    embedding_var = tf.get_variable("feature_embedding", ...)
    update_embedding = embedding_var.assign(predictions)
  ....
```

The problem is that `embedding_var` is only present in the evaluation graph. This causes the following error

```py
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key feature_embedding not found in checkpoint
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you make it a local variable? This is what metrics do. So it'd be `tf.get_variable("feature_embedding", collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES], ...)`